# Changing Word Document XML

Tags: c#, xml, ms-word

What I am doing is trying to change the value of a Microsoft Office Word documents XML and save it as a new file. I know that there are SDK's that I could use to make this easier but the project I am tasked with maintaining is doing things this way and I was told I had to as well.

I have a basic test document with two placeholders mapped to the following XML:

```
<root>
  <element>
     Fubar
  </element>
  <second>
     This is the second placeholder
  </second>
</root>
```

In my test project I have the following:

```
string strRelRoot = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument";
//the word template
byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes("dev.docx");
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer, true);
Package package = Package.Open(stream, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
//get the document relationship
PackageRelationshipCollection pkgrcOfficeDocument = package.GetRelationshipsByType(strRelRoot);
//iterate through relationship
foreach (PackageRelationship pkgr in pkgrcOfficeDocument)
{
    if (pkgr.SourceUri.OriginalString == "/")
    {
        //uri for the custom xml
        Uri uriData = new Uri("/customXML/item1.xml", UriKind.Relative);
        //delete the existing xml if it exists
        if (package.PartExists(uriData))
        { 
            // Delete template "/customXML/item1.xml" part
            package.DeletePart(uriData);
        }
        PackagePart pkgprtData = package.CreatePart(uriData, "application/xml");
           //hard coded test data
           string xml = @"<root>
                        <element>
                            Changed
                        </element>
                        <second>
                                The second placeholder changed
                        </second>
                    </root>";
        Stream fromStream = pkgprtData.GetStream();
        //write the string
        fromStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml),0,xml.Length);
        //destination file
        Stream dest = File.Create("test.docx");
        //write to the destination file
        for (int a = fromStream.ReadByte(); a != -1; a = fromStream.ReadByte())
        {
            dest.WriteByte((byte)a);
        }

    }
}
```

What is happening right now is the file test.docx is being created but it is a blank document. I'm not sure why this is happening. Any suggestions anyone could offer on this approach and/or what I am doing incorrectly would be very much appreciated. Thanks much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your `fromStream.Write` call, the stream pointer is positioned after the data you've just written. So your first call to `fromStream.ReadByte` is already at the end of the stream, and you read (and write) nothing.

You need to either `Seek` to the beginning of the stream after writing (if the stream returned by the package supports seeking), or close `fromStream` (to ensure the data you've written is flushed) and reopen it for reading.

```
fromStream.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! You were correct about needing to reset the pointer. I have modified my code and my goal slightly and posted the edits, if you could take a look I would be grateful, thanks!

Comment: @TheMethod That's quite a significant modification to your goal :P In short, you have to read the original XML before (or instead of) deleting the part containing it, then use one of the XML APIs to substitute the values you want before writing it back. To avoid making this question impossible to understand for anyone who hasn't seen its history, it'd probably be better to roll back your edit and ask a new question.